# How do I get rid of the arrow in a Tix.Balloon widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, tix

When I use the standard Tix.Balloon widget, bind it to a button and use a balloonmsg, I get the tooltip over the button, but I also get a stupid looking arrow inside the tooltip. ([See the demo code from the Python source tree here.](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Demo/tix/samples/Balloon.py?revision=78779&view=markup)) Is it possible to get rid of this arrow, or do I need to use another type of widget to get a normal looking tooltip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will set the arrow image to a blank bitmap

```
b = Tix.Balloon(root)
b.subwidget('label')['image'] = Tkinter.BitmapImage()
```

There are two subwidgets within a balloon, `label` which is the arrow and `message` which is the text.

I'm still new to python so there might be a better way to actually remove the arrow instead of just cover it up.

I am using Python 3.2